# Seaching for API to get number of search from google

Tags: java, google-api

I am trying to fetch the number of search results from google using following api
  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=" + site;

But the number of search results that I am getting from this api is not matching with google search result.
Is there any appropriate api to achieve the same